# Bootstrap 4 menu overlaps top area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4, this is HTML source

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block>-->
<!--For suggest css class purpose-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/bootstrap.min.css">-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <!--view-source:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <h3>Ngân hàng</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="finance_report.jsp">Báo cáo tài chính</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="balance_sheet_management.jsp">Bảng cân đối tài khoản (Mẫu quản trị)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="account_balance.jsp">Bảng cân đối tài khoản</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="balance_sheet.jsp">B01-DN: Bảng cân đối kế toán</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="income_statement.jsp">B02-DN: Báo cáo Kết quả hoạt động kinh doanh</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="obligation_with_state.jsp">Tình hình thực hiện nghĩa vụ với nhà nước</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="cash_flow_statement.jsp">B03-DN: Báo cáo lưu chuyển tiền tệ (PP trực tiếp)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="finance_statement_notes.jsp">B09-DN: Thuyết minh báo cáo tài chính</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</main><!-- /.container -->
<div>
    &copy; 2018 Do Nhu Vy
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
As you see, the menu overlaps the top area, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the classes `mt-5` and `pt-5` to the main `.container`.

Those are spacing classes for adding "margin-top" (`mt-*`) and "padding-top" (`pt-*`).

The reason you need those spacing classes, in this case, is because you are using the `fixed-top` class for the navbar. Without that class, you wouldn't need the spacing classes.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/